# how string split function works internally C#?

Tags: c#, string, split

I am new to strings and I am confused how string are splitting up for eg: in my code here I want to break a string with `,` and it's splitting into 9 parts but I am confused how it's splitting up please some one explain to me how it's breaking up:

```
string s31 = ",ONE,,TWO,,,THREE,,"; 

string[] s32 = s31.Split(ch31, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

> o/p

```
""
one
""
two
""
""
three
""
""
```

Comment: What's your question ? Do you wonder how split function works ?

Comment: What do you mean "how is it splitting up"? The question is not very clear. What's your issue with this code?

Comment: how it's spliting into 9 parts ? @Mennan

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen how it's spliing into 9 parts ?

Comment: "*how it's spliting into 9 parts*" -- there are 8 commas in your input. If you take a piece of wood and saw it 8 times, you end up with 9 pieces of wood.

Comment: How it does it - here's the reference source: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L997

Comment: you can use any .net decompiler like [this one](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/index) and check how the functions work

Comment: Easiest source to view and navigate around: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1ff97959e1d46a53

Comment: The result, by default, includes empty string fragments. Change `StringSplitOptions.None` to `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to only leave non-empty parts.

Comment: Split function searching for "comma char" into your string and creates array  between next comma or end of string.

Answer (score 3):

The split function is creating a new element on every occurrence of the comma. There are 8 commas in your string, so including the element before the first comma there will be 9 elements.

If you just want three elements, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, which will ignore the empty elements.